# REST WCF service is sending error 500 in HEAD instead of 404 not found

Tags: wcf, rest, iis

Here is my problem, I have a piece of WCF REST code that returns a NULL as suggested if the requested object in this case an image is not found. here is my code

```
if (imageStream == null) {
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetStatusAsNotFound("Image not available for the requested size.");
 return null;
}
```

This is sending a 404 error as expected in GET, but for HEAD is sending 500 Internal Server Error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);` Here is more about [WebFaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webfaultexception.aspx)

Comment: I tried with that instruction and it's still showing a 500 internal server error even when I indicated to return not found

if (imageStream == null)
{
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetStatusAsNotFound("Image not available for the requested size.");

WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = 0;

WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                }'